# Symfony Form: How to apply different themes/widgets to specific form fields?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

A Symfony 3.4 based form contains multiple `CheckboxType` fields. Some of these fields should be displayed as normal check boxes (= using the default checkbox widget) while some others should be displayed as on/off switches (like iOS `UISwitche`).

**So, within the same form fields of the same type (`CheckboxType`) should use different widgets. How can I do this?**

---

**Solution 1:** Of course I can apply a custom `form_theme` to the complete form (`{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:Form:myTheme.html.twig' %}`). But this effect **all** checkboxes within the form and not just only one. So this is not a solution.

---

**Solution 2:** A solution that would work is to apply a different widget to a one specific field using its id:

```
{% block _user_registration_form_someCheckBoxRow %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

While this solution works, I would have to create/override the same blocks for all effected field in all effected forms. This quite cumbersome and thus not a good solution.

---

**Solution 3:** Another solution that would work is to create a custom `FormType` to be used by the check boxes which should be displayed as switches. This form type would extend `CheckboxType` and do nothing but but override the `blockPrefix`.

While this comes pretty close to a good solution there is one major downside: Assume there are different themes / widgets for the check box switches. One with the label on top, one with the label next to the switch, etc. Each of these styles would not only need its own widget but also its own form type which need to be registered in the `FormPass.php`, etc. This would work of course but is also quite cumbersome and error prone.

So, this would be solution but not a `nice` one.

---

Isn't there a better way? I was searching for something like `{{ form_row(form.someCheckbox, 'someWidget') }}`. There would be only one extra file per theme and one could precisely tell which field uses which theme. No extra classes, config, etc. needed. I found nothing in this way.

**Is using dummy form types really the best solution?**

Comment: You could create your own form type, that extends the checkbox type doing nothing but overwriting the blockPrefix. This way you could theme that specific form type globally.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, this would work of course. One downside of this approach is, that it requires quite a lot of extra files, config, etc. I have edited the answer to describe what I mean.

Comment: Does it? It's been a while since 3.4, but with auto-wiring it would be one class, one config line, and one theme file?

Comment: This is correct. The extra work would not be the end of the world of course but it seems to be quite "a lot work" just to tell "Use them A on this field, theme B on this one and them C on this..."

Comment: Hmm, yes, another way would be to pass the [`block_prefix`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#block-prefix) via the options. Then you would only need the theme file. Which you'll always need anyway. Or to abstract things away, you could create only one custom checkbox type, that requires it's one option (e.g. checkbox-theme), but sets the block prefix based on that option. This should be possible with lazy option resolvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to my last comment above, the following works with Symfony 5.0.x (though no major changes should be required for 3.4, probably only some extra configuration):

To abstract the theme handling, define your own checkbox type, as follows (for example):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ThemedCheckboxType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'theme' => 'default',
                'block_prefix' => static function (Options $options): ?string {
                    return [
                        'default' => null,
                        'theme-a' => 'theme_a_checkbox',
                        'theme-b' => 'theme_b_checkbox',
                    ][$options['theme']];
                },
            ])
            ->setAllowedValues('theme', ['default', 'theme-a', 'theme-b']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return CheckboxType::class;
    }
}
```

Then simply use it where required, e.g.:

```
$builder->add('test_a1', ThemedCheckboxType::class, [
    'theme' => 'theme-a', // or others
]);
```

This way, you you can inject your own form theme, to directly manipulate the checkboxes when required, e.g.

```
{% block theme_a_checkbox_widget %}
    <em>Theme-A</em>
    {{ block('checkbox_widget') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block theme_b_checkbox_widget %}
    <em>Theme-B</em>
    {{ block('checkbox_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

If you don't want to use the extra form type, the same could be achieved using a custom form extension to add options to the default checkbox type. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html

For example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CheckboxTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [CheckboxType::class];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'theme' => 'default',
                'block_prefix' => static function (Options $options): ?string {
                    return [
                        'default' => null,
                        'theme-a' => 'theme_a_checkbox',
                        'theme-b' => 'theme_b_checkbox',
                    ][$options['theme']];
                },
            ])
            ->setAllowedValues('theme', ['default', 'theme-a', 'theme-b']);
    }
}
```

which allows for:

```
$builder->add('test_a1', CheckboxType::class, [
    'theme' => 'theme-a',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [a theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-different-themes-to-child-forms) to a single checkbox:

```
{% form_theme form.my_special_checkbox 'Form/Theme/special_checkbox.html.twig' %}
```

Or if you don't need a separate theme (single use case) you can write blocks in the current Twig file:

```
{% block _my_checkbox_widget_block %}
    {# the theme #}
{% endblock %}

{% form_theme form.my_special_checkbox _self %}
```

I would create custom checkbox component though with custom block name and put it inside a global form theme so I could reuse it across entire application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. While this would work to theme one specific field it would have the same disadvantages as the solution described in my question (`{% block _user_registration_form_someCheckBoxRow %}...`) when there are multiple (but not all) fields to theme.

Comment: That's why you can create custom checkbox type with a custom block name so you can reuse the same theme. Did you read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#fragment-naming-for-individual-fields)?